# How to transfer value after clicking a button in a UITableviewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

There is a `TableView` in `ViewController`.`TableViewCell` has a textView with some content. Now after clicking a `replyButton` in a `cell`, `segue` to `secondViewController`. I need to put content in the `textView` of the `cell`. How to do it? I used `indexPath` as code below but it crashed because `indexPath` is `nil`. Thanks for helping.

Clarification: I need to click the replyButton inside the cell to realize the goal, not by using didSelectRowAtIndexPath function.

[image]

code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


  @IBAction func replyButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toReplyVC", sender: self)

}


  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "toReplyVC" {

        let replyVC = segue.destination as! ReplyVC

  // code below did't work: 

   /*

         let indexPath = self.repliesTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

            let cell = self.repliesTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! ReplyCell

            replyVC.replyQuote = cell.replyTextView.text

    */    
       }
 }


}
```

Comment: are there any crash report or just value nil ? Give us a some explanation about your problem.

Comment: crashed because indexPath is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a protocol, in the Replycell.swift add this before the class

```
protocol ReplycellDelegate: class {
func didPressButtonFromCell(cellView: Replycell, id: int)}
```

inside the class add this

```
weak var delegate: ReplycellDelegate?
```

inside the button action in the cell add this

```
delegate?.didPressButtonFromCell(cellView: self, id: 2)
```

and now in the class ViewController after the uitableviewdatasource add RepplyCellDelegate, and then you just call the function `didPressButtonFromCell` and Xcode will autocomplete it for you, that function will be called when the button of the cell is pressed, if you have the content of the cell in the view controller add an id variable to the Repplycell class so you can pass it to each cell when is created, if you get the text in the Replycell class, instead of id in the protocol, declare a string and send it to the ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much wrong with the way you are trying to get the text-value, your are only doing it inside the wrong function. UITableView has a function `didSelectRowAt:indexPath` where it will work.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! Replycell
        replyVC.replyQuote = cell.replyTextView.text


    }
```

Comment: Hello Eric, I understand what you mean. I need to click the replyButton inside the cell, not the whole cell itself. so I didn't use didSelectRowAt indexPath function.